# recaptcha enterprise BROWSER_ERROR

Tags: recaptcha

I am trying to use recaptcha enterprise. I got the necessary key in the console, I registered the domain (and even tried turning off domain verification). Everything works well for me on localhost, but when I check on the server, I get the following error:

```
'java.lang.RuntimeException: The CreateAssessment call failed because the token was: BROWSER_ERROR (of class java.lang.RuntimeException)'.
```

Can you give me some pointers on where to start and where to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

created a new key in the console and everything worked on the destination domain